# Align text of a div center respect to the page

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

Can someone resolve my problem?
I have an header on my page with a central div and another div on the right side. I want to align the text of the H1 central respect the entire page, how can i do it?

```
<header>
    <div id="date"> 
        <p><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> WriteDate(true);</script></p>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="130" height="130"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div style="float:center;">
        <h1>Sito di Graizzaro Matteo</h1>
    </div>
</header>
```

The style of my page is:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 { 
    text-align: center;    
}
#date{
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Does `text-align:center` not work?

Comment: Are you sure `<header>` is the right name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date` has some width that will compromise centering the text.
You can:

- Give a negative `left` `margin` to virtually reduce its `width` to null

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  text-align: center;
}

#date {
  float: right;
  margin-left:-100%;
}
canvas {border:solid;}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="date">
    <p>01/01/01
    </p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="130" height="130"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align:center;">
    <h1>Sito di Graizzaro Matteo</h1>
  </div>
</header>
```

- or set its `width` to `0` and reset `direction` to let text overflow to the left

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  text-align: center;
}

#date {
  direction:rtl;
  float: right;
  width:0
}
canvas {border:solid;}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="date">
    <p>01/01/01
    </p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="130" height="130"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align:center;">
    <h1>Sito di Graizzaro Matteo</h1>
  </div>
</header>
```

- set it in `absolute` `position`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  text-align: center;
}

#date {
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
}
canvas {border:solid;}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="date">
    <p>01/01/01
    </p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="130" height="130"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align:center;">
    <h1>Sito di Graizzaro Matteo</h1>
  </div>
</header>
```

In any case `float:center` is not valid, you can either:

- use `text-align:center;` or
- `display:table;margin:auto` if container has to wrap on the text's width.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  text-align: center;
}

#date {
  direction:rtl;
  float: right;
  width:0
}
canvas {border:solid;}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="date">
    <p>01/01/01
    </p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="130" height="130"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div style="display:table;margin:auto;background:gray;">
    <h1>Sito di Graizzaro Matteo</h1>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
display: block;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
float: none;
```

on the heading element

Comment: The date will push the "centering" to the left, though.

Answer (score 0):

`float: center` isn't a thing. You want `text-align: center`.

Thing is, it still won't sit quite in the center - the date will push it off.

Here are two things you could do to get around this: first, rather than floating the date to the right, text-align it to the right, and use negative top margin on your title to pull it upward.

Or, rather than floating the date to the right, use absolute positioning with a `right` value of 0 to get it to sit on the right, and your header will center properly.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an id instead of `h1`, but with relative positioning you can put the text wherever you want adjusting the top and left parameters.

```
#date {
    position: relative;
}

.h1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 500;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<header>
    <div id="date"> 
        <p><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> WriteDate(true);</script></p>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="130" height="130"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Sito di Graizzaro Matteo</h1>
    </div>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
 // html and body can be other wrapper of the title
 // the important thing there is the "position:relative"
 html,body {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   position: relative }
h1 {
   margin: 0;
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;               
   top: 50%;      
   font-size: 40px;
   margin-top: -40px;
   transform: translate(0, -50%);
   text-align: center;}
```

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/nu35jhob/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 { 
    text-align: center;    
}
#date{
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div id="date"> 
        <p><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> document.write("12-Dec-2015 12:15:11");</script></p>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="130" height="130"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; width: 100%;">
        <h1>Sito di Graizzaro Matteo</h1>
    </div>
</header>
```